# Swift playground not working on iPad

Tags: ipad, swift-playground

I want to run playground on my iPad but I’m not able to create one.
When creating a blank playground I’m getting error as “Downloading error: Unknown file error”
None of the other playground are being downloaded.

Then I thought of creating one on my Mac and then using it on iPad. I created one blank playground on Mac and saved it to iCloud and then tried opening from iPad. I’m getting error as “Playground couldn’t be moved to “Documents” because either the former doesn’t exist or the folder containing latter doesn’t exist”

[image: trying to create blank playground on iPad]

[image: trying to open playground from iCloud]

I’m running iOS 11.3.1 on my iPad.
And I have also tried reinstalling playground app but doesn’t seems to work.

Comment: This seems to me as if some iCloud setup went wrong. Did you try deleting the Playgrounds app on your iPad as well as the iCloud folder belonging to it?

Comment: @JoRa Yes, I disabled the iCloud backup. It started running fine. But there is no playground folder on my iCloud Drive to delete. Now I am able to run it without iCloud backup. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe you can write an answer to your question and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disabled the iCloud backup for the Playground and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have this figured out. One or more of these steps may be unnecessary but this is what worked for me. You need a Mac with iCloud signed in to the same account as your iPad.

- On your iPad, make sure you have Playgrounds enabled in iCloud. `Settings > Name > iCloud > Playgrounds`.
- On your Mac, with iCloud signed in to the same account as your iPad, navigate to your iCloud Drive folder.
- Show hidden files by pressing `shift + command + .(period)` (I think this shortcut works on 10.13+ only, Google how to show hidden files otherwise.)
- The Playgrounds folder should appear, dimmed. (If it isn't there then this is where it ends for you!)
- Add a new folder to the Playgrounds folder. The Playgrounds folder should now be undimmed.
- On your iPad navigate back to iCloud settings `Settings > Name > iCloud` and turn off iCloud Drive.
- Re-enable iCloud Drive. Give it a sec while your documents are re-downloaded.
- Check in the Files app that the Playgrounds folder has re-appeared in iCloud Drive.
- You should now be able to download Learn to Code playgrounds, Challenges, and new Starting Points.